# How to turn line numbers's on on the left

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to programming, and I just downloaded c # however I cannot get the program to show the line numbers on the left so I can fix errors.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165340.aspx

Comment: do you mean visual studio? `tools` > `options` > `text editor` > `all languages` > tick the box for line numbers

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Line Numbers check box in the Display Section.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to display line numbers in the editor to find the errors in the code. There are several ways to find the line:

- Double click on a compiler error, and you will be moved to that line.
- The current line number is displayed to the right in the status bar at the bottom of the window.
- Press `Ctrl+G` and type in a line number to go to that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the line number (and column) of the currently selected line in the bottom right area of the screen.